# ModuleNotFoundError even though __init.py__ exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu, discord.py

I have a discord bot written with python. But the catch is, it only works when deployed on heroku but doesnot run locally at all.

This is the folder structure

```
- feed 
  - __init__.py
  - token.py
  - main.py
-requirements.txt
```

When I run the command `python3.9 feed/main.py`, it gives the following error:

```
    from feed import token
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'feed'
```

What is the issue here? Mind you that the code runs without any errors on heroku with the same command. I am on Ubuntu 21.04.

If I change feed to .feed, I get other errors regarding absolute imports.

Please don't redirect me to other answers, I have tried it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how Heroku works, but to get it running locally, try changing your import to:

```
import token
```

If you want to use feed as the parent directory, you can create a setup.py file and run `pip install -e .` in the folder. Then doing

```
from feed import token
```

should work as part of your development environment.

Comment: It was that simple all along. Thanks!!